# WP8 HttpClient Stream of Album Content

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm actually learning coding with Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Phone. Now I've already build an Application, that picks a Picture from the Gallery (with the `PhotoChooserTask`), an Uploads it via `HttpClient` to own Service. Now I want to Add the ability to to this for a complete PictureAlbum (CameraRoll etc).

How can I do this exactly? I'm an absolute beginner and searched the Web threw few Sites, but didn't find any "easy to understand" help or solution. Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are asking , i think you were asking how to do a image download and upload by httpclient. let me know if i m wrong

here is the solution,

First, you need a web api based on server, it provides HttpGet for download from a device, HttpPost for upload from a device.
for the web server or web api, you can take a look at [this](http://bitoftech.net/2013/11/25/getting-started-asp-net-web-api/)

Second, on the client windows phone side, u need to use HttpClient to do download and upload.

on how to use HttpClient, you can check [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/9b4c1ef2-853c-468a-bca8-97477a02583c/httpclient-for-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop).

on how to display images on the windows phone, check [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/PhotoHub-Windows-Phone-8-fd7a1093).

hope this is helpful for u.